# What is a better way to express, "right at this moment in time or this exact second"?

Tags: expressions

Example context:

> I am probably looking at the most beautiful person in the world right at this very moment.

I can only look at <strike>something</strike> one thing at a time and that's exactly I want to say. Please help, not a native.

Answer (score 0):

The word **now** carries the sense of `at this very moment`.

Oxford Dictionary

> At the present time or moment.

Your example can be summed-up as:

> I am probably looking at the most beautiful person **right now**.

I hope this helps!